# Is there a general formula for $\int_0^l x^n \sin(m\pi x/l) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

The integral
$$\int_0^l x^n \sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}l\right) dx$$
frequently arises for computing Fourier coefficients, for $m,n$ integers. Is there any general formula for that? What about $\cos$ instead of $\sin$?

Comment: Have you tried to integrate by parts two times to get a reccurence formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$J_{\sin}=\int_0^lx^n\sin\left(\dfrac{m\pi x}{l}\right)dx$$
$$J_{\sin}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}\left(\pi ml^{n+1}F^1_2\left(\dfrac{n}{2}+1;\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{n}{2}+2;-\dfrac{1}{4}m^2\pi^2\right)\right)$$
with$$\Re(n)\gt  2$$
and $$F^p_q(a_1...a_p;b_1...b_q;z)$$
is the generalized Hypergeometric function.

$$J_{\cos}=\int_0^lx^n\cos\left(\dfrac{m\pi x}{l}\right)dx$$
$$J_{\cos}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}\left(l^{n+1}F^1_2\left(\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2};\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{3}{2};-\dfrac{1}{4}m^2\pi^2\right)\right)$$
$$\Re(n)\gt -1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Just compute first
$$\int x^n e^{i\frac{\pi  m x}{l}}\,dx$$ and you will see the incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

Here we will address your integral:
\begin{equation}
J_{n,m}(l)=\int_0^l x^n \sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}l\right) dx
\end{equation}
First let $u = \frac{m\pi x}{l}$:
\begin{equation}
J_{n,m}(l)=\int_0^{m\pi} \left(\frac{l u}{m \pi}\right)^n \sin\left(u\right) \cdot \frac{l}{m\pi} \:du = \left(\frac{l}{m \pi}\right)^{n + 1} \int_0^{m \pi} u^n \sin(u)\:du
\end{equation}
From here it's a matter of simple recursion obtained via integration by parts.